# Finding the largest prime number "within" a number

Tags: python, performance, optimization

For this question, I need to find the largest prime number within a larger number. For the purpose of the example, let's say the larger number is "123456789", then some of the numbers I would have to check are 12, 456, 234567, etc.

I wrote some Python code to figure this out, but it is running very slow for the number I am trying to check. The actual number I am working with is about 10000 digits, so there are a lot of numbers I need to look at. Here is my code:

```
num = "123456789"

def isPrime(n):
# 0 and 1 are not primes
if n < 2:
    return False
# 2 is the only even prime number
if n == 2:
    return True
# all other even numbers are not primes
if not n & 1:
    return False
# range starts with 3 and only needs to go up the squareroot of n
# for all odd numbers
for x in range(3, long(n**0.5)+1, 2):
    if n % x == 0:
        return False
return True

def largestPrime():
    largest = 2
    for i in range(0,len(num)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(num)):
            if isPrime(long(num[i:j])):
                if long(num[i:j]) > largest:
                    largest =long(num[i:j])
    print largest

def main():
    largestPrime()

main()
```

I'm pretty sure this code gives the correct answer, but as I said, it's really slow. Can anyone help me figure out how to speed this up?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: One obvious improvement: rearrange the `if isPrime...if > largest` to `if >largest...if isPrime`, so you only check if it's prime if it's larger than the largest prime you've found so far (if it's smaller, you don't care whether it's prime or not).

Comment: There are many prime testing algorithms that are more efficient than the naive one you've written. Especially if you can accept false positives—which you can; all you have to do is keep a sorted list of the biggest "probably prime" numbers, and then at the end do the slow but guaranteed correct test on the biggest one. You'll need to do some research to pick the algorithm that best suits your needs, of course.

Comment: Your prime detection algorithm is the main bottleneck. Merely finding out if the whole 10000 digit number is prime is going to take a while with his algorithm. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test for better tests.

Comment: As a side note, starting with `largest=2` is a very tiny optimization, and considering that it means you can get incorrect values (e.g., try it on `100000000000`…), I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Finally, doing a tight loop over a bunch of arithmetic is exactly what Python is bad at. You want to push the inner loop (of `isPrime`) into C if at all possible. That's pretty easy to do by writing it in Cython. Or, there are clever ways to turn arithmetic on a huge number into vectorized arithmetic on a numpy array. Or just run your code in PyPy instead of CPython—sometimes (and more often with each version) it manages to JIT your code into reasonable speed. But don't worry about this until you've got a ZPP or similarly tractable algorithm.

Comment: Please fix your indentation...

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use the strategy of starting with the total number of digits and seeing if that's prime.  Then keep decreasing the digits by one while shifting over to the left to see if that's prime.  Let me explain with an example:

```
123456789

First check the 9-digit number: 123456789
Then check the 8-digit numbers: 23456789, 12345678
Then Check the 7-digit numbers: 3456789, 2345678, 1234567
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see is that for some large numbers you are going to be testing the same number many times. For example for '123456712345671234567', your code will test '1234567' 3 times. I suggest you make a set that contains no duplicates, then run your prime test on each number. I also think that sorting the numbers is a good idea because we can stop after the first prime is found.

Next if you are dealing with large numbers (e.g. 10000 digits), I suggest using a statistical primality test. Below I made a Miller-Rabin primality test using pseudocode from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Algorithm_and_running_time).

I have pretty much rewritten your code :P

```
import random
num = '3456647867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876867843652345683947582397589235623896514759283590784235876784235876324650'

def probablyPrime(num, k):
    """Using Miller-Rabin primality test"""
    if num == 2 or num == 3:
        return True
    if num < 2:
        return False
    if not num & 1:
        return False

    # find s and d such that n−1 = (2**s)*d with d odd
    d = (num-1) >> 1
    s = 1
    while not (d & 1):
        d = d >> 1
        s += 1

    # run k times
    for _ in range(k):
        a = random.randint(2, num-2)
        x = pow(a, d, num)  # more efficient than  x = a**d % num
        if not (x == 1 or x == num-1):
            for _ in range(s-1):
                x = (x**2) % num
                if x == 1:
                    return False
                if x == num-1:
                    break
            if not x == num-1:
                return False
    return True


def largestPrime(num):
    num_list = set([])
    for i in range(0,len(num)+1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(num)+1): 
            inum = int(num[i:j])
            # Don't append numbers that have already appeared
            if inum not in num_list:
                num_list.add(inum)

    # Convert to list and sort
    num_list = list(num_list)
    num_list.sort(reverse=True)

    for num in num_list:
        print('Checking ' + str(num))
        if probablyPrime(num,100):
            print('\n' + str(num) + ' is probably the largest prime!')
            return

largestPrime(num)
```

Another way to improve speed might be python's [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package.

Comment: The idea is good, but a list is a really bad data structure for this problem. Use a set.

Comment: I agree with Voo. I updated my code to use set. I have tested this script with some large numbers and the real slow down seems to be when isPrime() is working on 50+ digit numbers. I would look into a better prime test, but even with a very good one I bet a 10000 digit number will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return str(n)+" is the biggest prime"
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return isprime(n-1) #not prime, check again for next biggest number
    max = n**0.5+1
    i = 3
    while i <= max:
        if n % i == 0:
            return isprime(n-1) #not prime, check again for next biggest number
        i+=2
    return str(n)+" is the biggest prime"

print "Testing 7:",isprime(7)
print "Testing 23:",isprime(23)
print "Testing 2245:",isprime(2245)
print "Testing 222457:",isprime(222457)
print "Testing 727245628:",isprime(727245628)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> 
Testing 7: 7 is the biggest prime
Testing 23: 23 is the biggest prime
Testing 2245: 2243 is the biggest prime
Testing 222457: 222437 is the biggest prime
Testing 727245628: 727245613 is the biggest prime
```